# Does Paypal send an IPN if completed?

Tags: paypal, payment, message, paypal-ipn

what if someone pays in Germany with ELV (charge) and the payment is pending.

Does PayPal send an IPN for pending or only for completed?

What types of IPN messages are there?

Hope you can help me!

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this link under 'Payment_status' (Ctrl-F to find it helps).

[IPN integration guide/IPNvariables](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/)

To be honest not sure what a German ELV is but I believe an IPN is sent when the payment status is any of the listed payment_status (or atleast I have seen 'Pending', Completed, 'Refunded', 'Processed', 'Reversed' IPN's) so I can say you should get an IPN sent when it's 'Pending' as you ask about. You have turned on IPN sending to a handler file on your server, etc.? If so you should be able to store logfiles and read them and look for a line like:

payment_status : Completed

hope thats helped.

T